# Можно ли в шарпе перенести строку вывода на другую строчку как в c++

Tags: c#, консоль

В C++ часто делал так:

```cpp
cout << "text text text text text
     <<  text text text
     <<    text" << endl;
```

В C# компилятор ругает почему-то. Каким образом можно реализовать что-то подобное в C#, но при этом не инициируя новый вывод в консоль.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Console.WriteLine("""
    Multi
    Line
    String
    """);
```

```cs
var a = 4;

Console.WriteLine($"""
    it's also works:
    {a}
    """);
```